# Codeigniter 3 Postgresql Driver Error Code

Tags: error-handling, postgresql-9.3, codeigniter-3

Is there a workaround for me to get the error code. 
The driver returns empty string for $this->db->error() "code" index,
and it also uses pg_query() to execute that is why it will really not return an error code.

Comment: I've found a workaround and use PDO Driver instead

Answer (score 0):

First do you have to install the followin package: php5-pgsql

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql
```

then restart apache:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop 

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Now, you setup the file database.php of codeigniter 3

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'tu_usuario',
    'password' => 'tu_clave',
    'database' => 'tu_base_de_datos',
    'dbdriver' => 'postgre',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE,
    'port' => 5432,
);
```

Twitter: @luiscordero29

Comment: I can't speak to the code, but since the original post is in English, I would think you're response should also be for posterity.